# .vbs script doesn't run gnome-terminal unless I run the program in terminal first [WSL]

Tags: windows, gnome-terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have this vbs script that I've been using to run `gnome-terminal`from my Windows 10 Desktop. It executes the following commands in `strArgs` without showing terminal window that's executing the commands.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "wsl 'DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

However, the script works only if I execute `DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal` in my vanilla wsl terminal first. I'm not sure what its starting up in my processes that allows the script to work, but I really don't want to keep doing this every time I restart my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently adding the `read` command after `gnome-terminal` gets it to work. Now I don't need to enter the commands in a command window with every reboot to get the desktop shortcut to work.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "wsl 'DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal;read"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that DBus needs to be launched first. This batch script works for me, and also checks to make sure the VcXsrv is running:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq vcxsrv.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "vcxsrv.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo X server is running
if not "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" start "" "C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe" :0 -ac -terminate -lesspointer -multiwindow -clipboard -dpi auto
ubuntu run "sh -ic 'if [ -z \"$(pidof dbus-launch)\" ]; then export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0; dbus-launch --exit-with-x11; fi;'"
ubuntu run "DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/kevin; sleep 1"
```

Of course edit the directories, and change the command from `ubuntu` if you're using something else.